# Python Dictionary AZBY Sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build a program that will order my dictionary values in a particular way.

What I am trying to do is this -

If I have a dictionary of:

> - name1 : 1
> - name2 : 2
> - name3 : 3
> - name4 : 4
> - name5 : 5
> - name6 : 6
> - name7 : 7
> - name8 : 8

I want it to be organised by the highest with the lowest, then the second highest with the second lowest and so forth eg.

> 1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5  (A,Z,B,Y)

The data I am trying to sort is in a dictionary form and would just need to be printed in that order as it is just for a one time use and not to store.

I hope this is enough information.

ps. I am new to python so if explanations could be kept as simple as possible it would be great, also I am using python version 3.6

Comment: Do you want the keys printed or the values?  (`name1` or `1`)?

Comment: Try to post a [mcve] and tell us what you have tried.

Comment: @EthanK Apologies I am brand new to this website and don't particularly know much about what I am doing. I had tried some stuff before but none were close to being successful. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip the sorted values with the reversed sorted values and print the pairs.

```
d = {'name1': 1,
     'name2': 2,
     'name3': 3,
     'name4': 4,
     'name5': 5,
     'name6': 6,
     'name7': 7,
     'name8': 8}

v = sorted(d.values())
for x,y in zip(v[:len(v)//2], v[::-1]):
    print('{}, {}'.format(x,y), end=', ')
# prints:
1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5,
```

To print the keys based on the order of the values:

```
v = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[-1])
for x, y in zip(v[:len(v)//2], v[::-1]):
    print('{}, {}'.format(x[0], y[0]), end=', ')
```

Comment: You can also replace the `for` loop with a single `reduce`, correct?

Comment: You can, but I prefer not to put print statements in lambda functions or list comprehensions.

Comment: Well, it'd return a list which you can print later ... but I see your point – OP merely wants to *print* this anyway.

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks, but I don't know if this would be possible but is there a way to sort by the value but print the keys?   ie. name1,name8,name2,name7,...